# Meteor Tinytest package with its own main function

Tags: testing, meteor, program-entry-point

I have one small question - is it possible to use tinytest in package which has own main function? I have written package for MQTT protocol with mqttjs node module integration, and I have my own main function, where the server starts. Everything work perfectly, but I wanted to write some unit tests. My package is called mqttapp, so in package.js file I have added:

```
Package.on_test(function(api) {
  api.use(['mqttapp', 'tinytest', 'test-helpers']);
  api.add_files("test.js", 'server');
})
```

And in file test.js (code is from EventedMind):

```
Tinytest.add('Testing test for test - test', function (test) {
  test.equal(1, 1, 'Expected values to be equal');
});
```

After this, I go to my package folder and run

```
meteor test-packages ./
```

And after few seconds:

```
W20140315-16:18:42.923(1)? (STDERR) Program has more than one main() function?
```

I have tried to write test for package without own main function and everything works perfectly. So! Can I test it somehow?

I have to have my own main function, because many properties in package are set before server starts.

Thanks for any advice :)